About the symmetry of an operator
Let $\pmb{\sigma}=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ where $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ are the Pauli matrices, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\,
\sigma_2= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix},\,
\sigma_3= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Let $f,g\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{C}^{2})$. I am trying to show that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}(-i\,\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla f)\cdot(-i\,\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla g)\,dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\big(-i\,\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla(-i\,\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla f)\big)\cdot g\,dx
$$
Now, I know that
$$
(-i\,\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)(-i\,\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)=-(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)=-(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)^2=-\Delta
$$
I tried to compute the first integral, but i obtain that
$$
(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla f)\cdot(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla g)=\partial_1 f\,\partial_1 g-\partial_2 f\,\partial_2 g+\partial_3 f\,\partial_3 g
$$
so i am not able to explicit the laplacian.
This made me think that the equality I am trying to show is not true, but if someone will be so kind to help me, I would be really glad.

Given that the Pauli matrices are hermitian and the derivatives are antisymmetric, the operator $A = -i\pmb{\sigma\cdot\nabla}$ is hermitian too. In consequence, one has $\langle A\bar{f},Ag \rangle = \langle A^\dagger A\bar{f},g \rangle = \langle A^2\bar{f},g \rangle$, which is indeed the relation you tried to prove.

First of all, thank you verym uch for your answer.
Would you mind explaining why the fact that the Pauli matrices are hermitian and the derivatives are antisymmetric gives us that $A$ is hermitian?
By hermitian operator you mean self-adjoint?
And the last question I have is that by $\langle\cdot , \cdot\rangle$ i think you mean the scalar product, but I am not really sure if
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f(x),g(x),dx$$ is a scalar product since both $f, g$ are complex valued.

@Davide  (1) I didn't see that the functions were complex-valued. In consequence, one must consider the scalar product you wrote, except that $f$ has to be replaced by its complex conjugate. (2) Yes, hermitian means self-adjoint. (3) Derivatives are antisymmetric; in consequence, their adjoint will bring a minus sign, which will be here compensated by the minus sign produced by the complex conjugation of $i$, while the Pauli matrices are their own adjoint due to hermicity.
